# Spiders in my plant (not spider mites)

Tags: houseplants, plant-health

I am wondering if it is ok to let the spiders I have in my plants live? 
The plants seem happy, going about its day (its a maranta leconeura and a calathea orbifolia) 
Both plants don’t seem to have any illnesses or pest and they are giving me many new leafs. 
I’ve read somewhere that letting the spiders (regular, not spider mites) live in peace in the plant is healthy and helping me keep the pests and flies away. 
Is this true? [image]

Answer (score 2):

Normally spiders are not harmful to plants. They are predators, so they eat mostly other animals (insects). If you don't mind the spiders in your home, you can leave them in your plant pots. I have seen however once in my own plants that they built a nest and this resulted in folding the leaves into a clump. This also resulted in many tiny spiders, so I removed it then. But not really harmful thus.

Comment: Great, then they can stay  but if it comes to that I will have to move them out  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All spiders are good guys.  Even the Hobo, the Wolff and the aggressive house spider who do not belong indoors, just catch them and take them out of doors.

Baby spiders are a wonder.  To kill spiders and baby spiders is just wrong, sorry, but that is a fact.  I watched in horror as some scaredy cat human smashed a mother spider trying her best to get out of this kitchen and out of doors...including the baby spiders on her back.  It will always be a nightmare for me!

Spiders as most animals/insects are territorial.  Too many of one species over populating an area is detrimental to the species so when you see an individual spider know that they will never 'over' populate.  Spiders are the number one predator for all normal noxious insects.  People who order pesticide companies to come in and kill all insects to include spiders are setting themselves up for a very bad infestation of some kind in the near future.  They are killing all the normal controls!  Spiders are so important and beneficial.

When a mommy spider has babies those babies go elsewhere!  Such wonderful animals, spiders.  There is never TOO many spiders!  Spiders are scary for a reason.  I helped my own fear of spiders by raising a Rosy Toed Tarantula.  I had to get drunk out of my mind to hold it in my hand...but it was fine.  Spiders are excellent, unpaid, insect control dudes.